# Necesito aumentar max_input_vars en Centos 7 ya edite php.ini y htaccess y no funciona

Tags: php, .htaccess, variables, centos, configuración

Comunidad, mi caso es que tengo un servidor en **Digital Ocean** con `Centos 7 x64` y estoy usando `Centos Panel`.

En una de las cuentas mi cliente requiere que aumente la variable de Php `max_input_vars` a `5000` pero ya edite el **"php.ini"**, **"user.ini"**, y **".htaccess"**. Prácticamente todos los métodos conocidos, y aun se mantiene en el valor por defecto `1.000`

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: ¿Has reiniciado el servicio de `php-fpm` o en su defecto Apache (`httpd`)?

Comment: Hola no había visto la respuesta pero la solución fue que para cada versión de PHP hay un php.ini con la configuración de cada uno, solo tuve que ir a la carpeta de php 5.3  (ya que esa carpeta del servidor estaba configurada para usar solo php 5.3) y editar el php.ini.